# Ensure value is in list when inserting / updating

Tags: mariadb, check-constraints, mariadb-10.5

is it possible to ensure that a value is in a list of values defined in another table? For instance by using a check constraint?

I was thinking about a construct like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `possible_value`
(
    id_possible_value INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
  , concerning_table VARCHAR(50)
  , concerning_column VARCHAR(50)
  , value VARCHAR(100)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `event`
(
    id_event INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
  , id_foreign INTEGER NOT NULL
  , concerning_table VARCHAR(50)
  , name VARCHAR(50)
  , class VARCHAR(20)
  , CONSTRAINT class_is_possible CHECK(
        class IN (
            SELECT      value
            FROM        possible_value
            WHERE       concerning_table = 'event'
                    AND concerning_column = 'class'
        )
    )
);
```

But I think a check constraint cannot access information from another table.

Thanks in advance

Markus

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: Why not just use a normal Foreign Key (with separate list tables, rather than a horrible ListToEndAllLists)? `CONSTRAINT class_is_possible FOREIGN KEY (class) REFERENCES PossibleClass (class)`

Comment: I'm using: Server version: 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 Debian 11

Comment: The idea of a unified table is to avoid multiple "satelite" tables. I have a lot of tables with fields limited to a range of values. Would I need a "possible value table" for each table / field?

Comment: Yes, a single table is a ridiculous idea, as noted by @AndriyM. below. At best, you cuold have worked around it by using a "polymorphic association" so that the referencing table has a `tableName` computed column over which the foreign key goes, but it quicky becomes unmanageable.

Answer (score 0):

I would abandon the idea to have a common reference table for multiple tables and columns.  There are existing mechanisms that allow you to have what you want in an efficient, declarative-only manner.

#### 1. Declare the column as `ENUM`

Could be used if the allowed value set is relatively small and static (or at least rarely needs updating).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `event`
(
    id_event INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
  , id_foreign INTEGER NOT NULL
  , concerning_table VARCHAR(50)
  , name VARCHAR(50)
  , class ENUM('event_class_1', 'event_class_2', 'event_class_3')
);
```

#### 2. Create a dedicated reference table of event class values

If the possible value set is rather large or if it is expected to change often, create `event_class`, a table that would serve as a reference specifically for that column of that table.  Make `value` the primary key and only column.  Declare the `class` column of the `event` table a foreign key referencing `event_class`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `event_class`
(
    value VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `event`
(
    id_event INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
  , id_foreign INTEGER NOT NULL
  , concerning_table VARCHAR(50)
  , name VARCHAR(50)
  , class VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  , FOREIGN KEY fk_event_event_class (class)
    REFERENCES event_class (value)
);
```

Basically, this would mean splitting your single `possible_values` table into multiple individual tables each serving as a reference for its own table and column as defined by your current `concerning_table` and `concerning_column` values.

#### 3. Same as #2 but have main table store references instead of actual values

Same as previously, create an `event_class` table but with a surrogate primary key column this time (possibly, but not necessarily, with auto-increment).  In the `event` table, replace the `class` column with a foreign key reference.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `event_class`
(
    id_event_class INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  , value VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  , UNIQUE KEY uq_event_class_value (value ASC)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `event`
(
    id_event INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
  , id_foreign INTEGER NOT NULL
  , concerning_table VARCHAR(50)
  , name VARCHAR(50)
  , id_event_class INTEGER NOT NULL
  , FOREIGN KEY fk_event_event_class (id_event_class)
    REFERENCES event_class (id_event_class)
);
```

Despite my suggesting it last, this would actually be my preferred approach.  Although you would have to use a join to fetch an actual class name/value in each query requiring that data, I would consider that to be a small price for more efficient storage (`INTEGER` vs `VARCHAR(20)`), which could very well translate into better performance.

With this approach, it would also be easier to modify an existing class value, as you would only have to update a row in `event_class`.  In contrast, with approach #2, modifying an existing class value would require adding a new row to `event_class`, replacing all the old class values in `event` with the new one, and finally removing the old value from `event_class`.